# Resources on understanding the Orchestrated objective reduction

Tags: perception, consciousness

I was trying to understand the mathematics behind the theory of [*Orchestrated objective reduction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestrated_objective_reduction), and clearly, first I read the original paper of Penrose & Hameroff. Then I tried some other related papers (reviews, critics, etc.), yet, I could not find any straightforward math behind this theory in any of my searchings.

Are there any references and resources on the mathematics of Orchestrated objective reduction?